# Add a string with comma in CSV file python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a CSV file that contains all the objects from my Django model. The model contains a price field which I would like to display as 1,500 in CSV, but it sets 1500 when writing data to CSV.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Finance Report %s to %s.csv'%(from_date, to_date)
writer = csv.writer(response, csv.excel)
response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))  # BOM (optional...Excel needs it to open UTF-8 file properly)
writer.writerow([key.replace('_', ' ').title() for key in vars(queryset[0]).keys()])
for obj in queryset:
    writer.writerow([str(key) for key in vars(obj).values()])

return response
```

How should I add comma separted amount field in the response csv.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.7 you could use this to format an integer into string that has commas in it:

```
'{:,}'.format(1500)
```

You just have to figure out which field is the price field so you could apply the above code to it.

Please read [python doc about format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: Actually I have done the formatting correctly. The issue that I am facing is when I am writing the formatted string to CSV then it removes the commas. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the formatting for that field like this:

```
for obj in queryset:
    values = [str(key) for key in vars(obj).values()]
    # Replace 3 with the price field index in values list
    values[3] = '{:,}'.format(values[3])

    writer.writerow(values)
```

Comment: Actually I have done the formatting correctly. The issue that I am facing is when I am writing the formatted string to CSV then it removes the commas. What should I do for that?